# Textbox enter key alternative for mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-input

I have a textbox for entering details

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" id="myText"/>
```

and I like to save the entered details when the Enter key is pressed. I can achieve that with the following code.

```
$('#myText').live("keypress", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          alert("Enter pressed");
          -- code for saving
      }
});
```

But if I use a mobile device, I won't be able to press the Enter key. How do I get this feature in the same?

I want it to be able to use in both computer and mobile devices, and this is not a form submit, because I have some other textboxes too.. I want to save the only textbox in which enter key is pressed

Comment: Why are you not able to press the enter key on a mobile device? https://output.jsbin.com/ritijidebe/ logs all keycodes and correctly identifies enter as *13* when I use it on my phone (on my Android version the key is labelled "Go" but it's still an enter key)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `onchange` method,

```
$('#myText').change(function(e) {
      alert("Value changed");
      -- code for saving
    }
});
```

Comment: but in this, the text will be saved for every character I type, I only ant to save when I click enter after complete typing

Comment: Onchange will trigger when you click out of the input box so i dont think it will trigger for every characters you enter.

Comment: Yes pressing the tab will trigger the method.